# Rails 3 different autocomplete fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view, textfield, jquery-autocomplete

I have 2 different autocomplete fields on a page each to be populated from different sources in the database.  My problem is when I test the page, the two autocomplete behaviors sometimes get switched in each others text fields.

My view partials looks like the following (I followed a [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised)):

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.text_field :ability_title, {:class => 'autocomplete_field', data: { autocomplete_source: abilities_path } } %>
  <%= f.label :points %>: <%= f.text_field :points %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <%= f.text_field :mission_title, {:class => 'autocomplete_field', data: {autocomplete_source: missions_path } } %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

My javascript:

```
jQuery ->
  $('fieldset').live 'click', ->
    $('.autocomplete_field').autocomplete
      source: $('.autocomplete_field').data('autocomplete-source')
```

And My controllers:

```
def index
  if params[:term].present?
    @abilities = Ability.search_titles(params[:term])
  else
    @abilities = Ability.all
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @abilities }
  end
end

def index
  if params[:term].present?
    @missions = Mission.search_titles(params[:term])
  else
    @missions = Mission.all
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @missions.map(&:title) }
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Try if this works                                              source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to differentiate both text fields by ids, eg:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.text_field :ability_title, {:id => 'autocomplete_field1', data: { autocomplete_source: abilities_path } } %>
  <%= f.label :points %>: <%= f.text_field :points %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <%= f.text_field :mission_title, {:id => 'autocomplete_field2', data: {autocomplete_source: missions_path } } %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
My javascript:

jQuery ->
  $('fieldset').live 'click', ->

    $('#autocomplete_field1').autocomplete
      source: $('#autocomplete_field1').data('autocomplete-source')
    $('#autocomplete_field2').autocomplete
      source: $('#autocomplete_field2').data('autocomplete-source')
```

EDIT:
more elegant solution:

```
jQuery ->
  $('fieldset').live 'click', ->
    $('#autocomplete_field1, #autocomplete_field2').each (index, element) =>
      $(element).autocomplete
        source: $(element).data('autocomplete-source')
```

Comment: This works but I find it a little inelegant.  Is there any clean way to avoid the duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works replace source in your js file

```
source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source')
```